# Refactoring C++ on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, refactoring

I'm using the default Xcode these days to do all of my coding, but Im interested in finding something to help with code refactoring.  I have a bunch of older projects I want to clean up.  Besides variable renaming, Xcode is lacking here.

1) I'm interested in the general consensus for the best option for a Mac user.

2) Now that Xcode 8 has been released with editor extensions, does anyone expect to see anyone develop any refactoring tools?  Or is that sort of functionality past what editor extensions are allowed to do?  I'm having a hard time finding any editor extensions that may have been developed so far.

I'm really looking to find something with function extraction.  I've seen a few other threads like this, but I'm interested in an updated version along with any comments on the capabilities of Xcode 8's editor extensions.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Been using AppCode recently for all my C++ refactoring, great tool as its refactoring is really great and their student policies are extremely generous (free year of subscription on all of their products for each year you prove you are a student).  With that being said, I'm still really wondering about Xcode extensions and if they can be used to refactor C++.  I'm not seeing any news on these extensions at all, like developers aren't making anything.  Curious to know what everyone else things.